# How much size is enough for volume group on debian 10 with luks encryption?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, luks

I'm installing Debian 10 on my laptop with LUKS full disk encryption via partitioning guide (Recommended for new users).

Now it asks me about the `amount of volume group to use for guided partitioning`.

I have a 1TB Hard disk.

There is a note on the page and says:

```
You may use the whole volume group for guided partitioning, or part of it. 
If you use only part of it, or if you add more disks later, then you will 
be able to grow logical volumes later using the LVM tools, so using a smaller 
part of the volume group at installation time may offer more flexibility.
```

I didn't choose home partition during the installation, does the above sentence make sense if I have only root partition?

If yes, How much size should I specify for the volume group? min and max?

THANKS.

Comment: Use the entire sleeve for your Volume Group, but allocate, say, only 30 GB for the Logical Volume holding the root filesystem. You can grow it later when you need to, but you've also got source to create extra LVs for other filesystems, for example if you decide to split off `/home`

Comment: @roaima I have no choice for choosing 30GB for the Logical Volume on root filesystem.
There is only one partition which is /root/.

I may misunderstood your comment, so do you mean that I should set 999.1GB of the space (all) to the Volume Group?

Comment: Also the default amount of swap is 1GB after installation, I installed Debian once in the past, and I couldn't see a separate SWAP partition, it was part of the Filesystem with 999GB space, but the swap had 1G space when I check it with a command.

Is there any way to increase SWAP? should I now leave some space for that?